# Is it possible to replace a beamer side bar by an image?

Tags: beamer, themes

Everything is in the question.
I would like to build a template for presentation (similar to a corporate PP presentation) including a background image on the left side of the slide.
I was thinking of using the Hannover theme and replacing the color left side bar by the image, without success yet.
Any suggestion welcomed.

EDIT : The solution proposed by @samcarter works fine for the current slides, but I could not succeed to make it work for title slide :

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % Beamer settings
\usetheme{Hannover} 

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar}{\includegraphics[width=1.5\beamer@sidebarwidth,height=\paperheight]{images/title_sidebar}} %
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{\includegraphics[width=1.5\beamer@sidebarwidth,height=\paperheight]{images/slide_sidebar}} 
\makeatother

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %  Other packages
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title[short title\hspace{0.25\textwidth}\hfil\insertpagenumber]{Looooooooooooooooong title of the presentation}
\date[xxx 2018]{Congress name\\
Congress date and place}
\author[X]{authors}%
\institute{\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Institution_logo}
}

\begin{document}
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Current slide}
Bla bla
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Why simply substituting 'sidebar left' by 'sidebar' doesn't work ?

Comment: Don't specify both width and height, just one of them.

Comment: Please see my edited answer for the title page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{\includegraphics[width=\beamer@sidebarwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

(for the real world case, provide an image with suitable dimensions and specify either the width or the height, but not both)

---

To use this also for the title page:

```
{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Exactly what I wanted, I only need to slightly adjust the width of the side bar to fit and not distort the image.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this issue, this works OK for the running slides and I thought I could do the same for the titile slide by substituting 'sidebar left' by 'sidebar', but it doesn' t work. Any hint ?

Comment: @DRi Can you make a MWE?

Comment: OK but it just puts the same sidebar as on the other slides, on the title page. And, yes, I am picky, but I'd rather have a special image for the title page sidebar

Comment: @DRi ??????????